# How to prove a nonlinear tracendent equation has two positive roots?

Tags: roots

How to show (but do not use numerical software such as Mathematica, Matlab...etc.) that this equation
\begin{equation}
\frac{u (83811
   u-88223)+18076}{396-3276
   u}-\frac{10 \log
   (u)}{3}-\frac{1}{2} \log
   \left(\frac{98 u+14}{273
   u-33}\right)=0
\end{equation}
has two roots $u_1$ and $u_2$ with $u_1,u_2>0$?

Comment: Why?????????????????????

Comment: Because numerical evidences show that two positive roots exist, I would like to try proving this fact by using mathematical analysis. (Intermediate Value Theorem might be helpful?)

Answer (score 0):

Well, you can find the answers numerically first (but do not include in your write up). Make sure the function above satisfies intermediate-value theorem. And then just show there is a sign change around the values near the numerically determined solutions, and therefore there must be two solutions. Something like that should work.

Comment: What if the roots are of even multiplicity?

Comment: @Kevin: saying a root is of even multiplicity only makes sense for polynomials (although one could consider the exponent of the first non-zero term in the function's Taylor series around the zero, if it is differentiable) but besides, the answer provides a sufficient condition, not one that is strictly necessary.